# Permission denied problems after rsync with sudo on the remote

Tags: permissions, rsync

I was trying to move files from one server to another.  From the source server, I ran `sudo rsync`.   The process was done, but on the destination server, I'm getting permission denied with `ls`and `cd`. I tried

```
sudo chown -R www-data:www-data dest
```

`www-data` is what `nginx` runs under.   but I'm still getting "permission denied" when I try to `cd`.  When I do `ls` without `sudo`, all attributes appear as a question mark `?`.  How do I fix this without changing read/write permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment yet, and I am not sure I understand the problem but I'll give it a shot.

- Set the directories as executable for all users ([source](https://serverfault.com/questions/65616/question-marks-showing-in-ls-of-directory-io-errors-too))
- add the user you login as to the www-data group if the directories are executable for the group

(Or do you not want to change executable permissions either?) then, assuming the directory has enabled execute for the user, you would have to login on the remote server as www-data (or are you doing that already? you don't mention..)

Comment: yes turned out that's the issue. I didn't notice the permission on the main directory was wrong. thanks